# How do I connect to an MySQL Database in Java safely (Read-Only)?

Tags: java, mysql

--> When connectig JAVA to MySQL DB directly --> The user (where the Program is running) still has Write acces & Username & Password to the DB, which I would like him not to have.

I want to put something in between JAVA and the MySQL Db so the has just read acces ... user would just need to read License status (blocked, flagged, OK) and category.

Cannot this be done by somehow putting somethin in between JAVA and MySQL DB?

I know that it's very unsafe to do like directly from JAVA TO MySQL DB since some "bad guys" could just have read and write acces to the whole database and just compromise some data.

So what I am asking for is not an finished script or code which does this, but rather an Question how I can make such an safe "Read-Only" Request, by the Java Program, to my Database.

I heard something that you can do it by an PHP-Script in between but I don't know the + and - or how to even start implementing an PHP Script into Java?!

Comment: ok, you commented it is not about a secure connection but about restriction to read access. you could use read-only [roles](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/roles.html).

Comment: But the User has still the Username and Password to the MySQL DB. Even if it's compiled, JAVA can be decompiled easily. I am looking moreover for something to put in between JAVA and MySQL DB

Comment: @codemanian_helloworld Why not use a MySQL user account which has only read access to the tables you want. No need to use a user account which has full access to everything when it shouldn't.

Comment: @Progman that's a good Point. Do you think this is an safe approach combined with TLS/SSL?

Are there any negative aspects with this method?

Comment: Also the User would than have acces to every entry of the DB (the DB will consist of some Hundres entries, some of them may be sensitive) ...

Answer (score 1):

You can change the access permissions a MySQL user account has, see [6.2 Access Control and Account Management](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/access-control.html). Provide a user account which has only read access to the tables it should have. That way, even with the login data stored in the application, you still can only *read* data from MySQL and not *write*/*change* data.